# LoadTest SoapUI not work with script to increse value

Tags: groovy, soapui, load-testing

I use soapUI 4.5.1.
I have a TestSuite with 4 steps, see below, and a Load Test.
Now I will say what each TestStep do in this context.
- Properties; I create one variable "number" and set a value ( eg: 100);
- Groovy Script : I increment this variable with (+1) and set the new value;
- Property Transfer : I transfer the value from variable "number" and put on element in XML inside the Request.
My goal it is run the LoadTest "LoadTest-Request" and check the time for each request on interval of 60 seconds.

[image: SoapUI Project]

SoapUI_4_5_1.png
My problem it is that each request don't update with the new value executed on Step "Property Transfer".

Comment: May be you need to show what groovy script contains and how property transfer is defined. More over, if groovy script is used, then property transfer may not required. Also, if `context`is used in groovy, then loadTest does not work as that variable is not available during load test. Please edit your question and update the above info.

Comment: Thanks all.
Below I will show the complete scenery of this Load Test. [Complete LoadTest](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Abqt.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution from this question is [here](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/LoadTest/m-p/117672#U117672)

Answer: 
The scope of property was the problem. When I change this scope and used the scope from TestCase, work correct.